# Select rows from behave table in Python

Tags: python, bdd, python-behave

I am using the behave framework for developing tests in Python. At the moment, I have a scenario outline and examples underneath it. I would like to be able to just select one of these examples at any time and run the test feature on that example. How would I go about doing it? Right now, whenever I invoke behave from the command line it executes the scenario against every example entry in the Examples behave table I have under my Scenario Outline.

EDIT: I have attached a screenshot to make things more clear.

[image]

This example is from behave's documentation. If we have a look under the Consumer Electronics table, we see 2 rows, for which the Scenario Outline will run (so it will run twice). Say I would like to test for one of these examples, and we had 20 of these examples (meaning 20 rows). How would I be able to choose just one of them instead of running my behave tests and having to wait for the Scenario Outline to finish all cases (if the example I want is the last entry on the table for example).

Comment: Can you show an example please? I'm not sure what you mean by "examples"?

Comment: @idjaw I have attached a photo and description for you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way I had done this was to have multiple 'Examples' tables with different names. Then pass the `--name` parameter when behave is called.

Answer (score 2):

Use the `--name` parameter but specify the number of the desired Examples block and the number of the desired example within it. Both numbers count from 1.

So for this scenario outline:

```
Scenario Outline: Blenders
   Given I put <thing> in a blender,
    when I switch the blender on
    then it should transform into <other thing>

 Examples: Amphibians
   | thing         | other thing |
   | Red Tree Frog | mush        |

 Examples: Consumer Electronics
   | thing         | other thing |
   | iPhone        | toxic waste |
   | Galaxy Nexus  | toxic waste |
```

to put only the Galaxy Nexus into the blender:

`behave --name 'Blenders -- @2.2' blenders.feature`

I usually start by running the whole feature and then narrow down by copy-pasting a specific `--name '...'` because `behave` always echoes each encountered scenario, in this exact format.

Answer (score 0):

The only option I can think of now is to specify the exact line for behave like this: `behave blenders.feature:12`

SpecFlow for example would let you specify a tag for example blocks, behave for python unfortunately does not AFAIK.